# Displaying related records from two different objects one after the other in angular

Tags: angular

I am basically trying to loop through two angular objects and displaying data from both that are related. The records are related by LegalParentClassId.

```
So for e.g Consider you have three records

   Id     Name  
    23456  Test

    Id     Name 
    23457  Test1

    Id     Name   LegalParentClassId
    23458  Test2  23456
```

It should then in the UI render in the following sequence

```
23456,  23458,  23457
```

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/b69dphxr/

The problem that I am facing is that it is displaying the matching record from the second object

UI

```
<table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
    <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c }}</th>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let s of data1;">
             <ng-container *ngIf="f.Id == s.LegalParentClassId">  
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
     </ng-container> 
  </ng-container>

  </tr>
  </table>
```

Actual Markup

```
 <div *ngIf="LegalFundClasses && LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel && ColumnNames">
        <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
            <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
                <ng-container *ngIf="c != ColumnNames[45] && c != ColumnNames[46] && c != ColumnNames[47] || isHurdle;">
                    <th
                        [ngClass]="c != ColumnNames[56] && c != ColumnNames[57] && c != ColumnNames[38]? 'tableItem bold' : 'tableItem cellbgcolor'">
                        {{ c }}</th>

                   <ng-container *ngFor="let f of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel; let i=index">

                        <!-- <ng-container *ngFor="let s of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel;" *ngIf="f.Id == s.LegalParentClassId"> -->

                           <!-- <ng-container *ngIf="f.Id == s.LegalParentClassId">   -->

                        <td class="tableItem"  *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
                        <td class="tableItem"  *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
                        <td class="tableItem"  *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
                        <td class="tableItem"  *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[3]">COMMERCIAL TERMS</td>
                        <td  class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[4]">
                            <div *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id]">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" style="float: left;"
                                    (click)="reviewClicked(f.Id,1)">Review Terms</button>
                                <!-- <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.AuditSummary" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" />
                  <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.AuditSummary" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" /> -->
                                {{f.AuditSummary}}
                            </div>
                        </td>



                        <td colspan=i class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[5] && i<1"></td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[6]" class="tableItem"> {{f.PrimaryCurrencyName}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id]  && c == ColumnNames[6]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist  style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.CurrencyId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.Currencies" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>


                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[7]" class="tableItem"> {{f.ManagerStrategyName}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[7]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.ManagerStrategyId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.ManagerStrategies" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[8]" class="tableItem"> {{f.OtherCurrencyName}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[8]" class="tableItem">

                            <kendo-multiselect [data]="LegalFundClasses.Currencies" style="height: 29.5px;"
                                [(ngModel)]="f.OtherCurrencyName" [textField]="'Name'" [valueField]="'Id'"
                                [autoClose]="false">
                                <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" [checked]="isItemSelected(dataItem.Name)">
                                    <label class="k-checkbox-label">{{ dataItem.Name }}</label>
                                </ng-template>
                            </kendo-multiselect>

                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[9]" class="tableItem"> {{f.SubVotingName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[9]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.SubVotingId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqVoting" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[10]" class="tableItem"> {{f.SubHotIssueName}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[10]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.SubHotIssueId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqHotIssue" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>

                        <td colspan=i class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[11] && i<1"> </td>

                        <td colspan=i class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[12] && i<1"></td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[13]" class="tableItem">{{f.RedsFrqncyName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[13]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.RedsFrqncyId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqRedsFrequency" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>

                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[14]" class="tableItem">{{f.RedsNoticeDays}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[14]" class="tableItem" >
                            <!-- <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.RedsNoticeDays" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" >  -->
                            <kendo-numerictextbox [(ngModel)]="f.RedsNoticeDays" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;">
                            </kendo-numerictextbox>
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[15]" class="tableItem">{{f.NoticeTypeOfDaysName}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[15]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.NoticeTypeOfDaysId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqTypeOfDays" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>

                        </td>

                        <td colspan=i class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[16] && i<1"></td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[17]" class="tableItem">{{f.LockupTypeName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[17]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.LockupTypeId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqLockupType" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>

                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[18]" class="tableItem">
                            {{f.HardDurationMonthsName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[18]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;"
                                [(ngModel)]="f.HardDurationMonthsId" [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
                                class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqDurationMonths"
                                [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>

                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[19]" class="tableItem">
                            {{f.SoftDurationMonthsName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[19]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;"
                                [(ngModel)]="f.SoftDurationMonthsId" [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
                                class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqDurationMonths"
                                [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>

                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[20]" class="tableItem">{{f.LockupFees0To12Pct}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[20]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-numerictextbox [(ngModel)]="f.LockupFees0To12Pct"
                                style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;"></kendo-numerictextbox>
                            <!-- <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.LockupFees0To12Pct" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" /> -->
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[21]" class="tableItem">{{f.LockupFees12To24Pct}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[21]" class="tableItem" >
                            <kendo-numerictextbox [(ngModel)]="f.LockupFees12To24Pct"
                                style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;"></kendo-numerictextbox>
                            <!-- <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.LockupFees12To24Pct" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" /> -->
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[22]" class="tableItem">{{f.LockupFees24To36Pct}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[22]" class="tableItem" >
                            <kendo-numerictextbox [(ngModel)]="f.LockupFees24To36Pct"
                                style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;"></kendo-numerictextbox>
                            <!-- <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.LockupFees24To36Pct" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" /> -->
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[23]" class="tableItem">{{f.WebfolioRedsFee}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[23]" class="tableItem">
                            <!-- <kendo-numerictextbox [(ngModel)]="f.WebfolioRedsFee" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;"></kendo-numerictextbox> -->
                            <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.WebfolioRedsFee" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" />
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[24]" class="tableItem">{{f.LockupComments}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[24]" class="tableItem" >
                            <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.LockupComments" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" />
                        </td>

                        <td colspan=i class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[25] && i<1"></td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[26]" class="tableItem">
                            {{f.ApplyGateDecliningBalance === 'true' ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[26]" class="tableItem">
                            <label style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;cursor: pointer">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.ApplyGateDecliningBalance}}"
                                    style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" /> Yes </label>
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[27]" class="tableItem">{{f.GateInvestorPct}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[27]" class="tableItem"><input kendoTextBox
                                [(ngModel)]="f.GateInvestorPct" style="height: 29.5px;" /></td>


                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[28]" class="tableItem">{{f.GateSourceName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[28]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.GateSourceId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqGateSource" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[29]" class="tableItem">{{f.GateFundClassPct}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[29]" class="tableItem">
                            <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.GateFundClassPct" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" />
                        </td>


                        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[30]"></td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[31]" class="tableItem">{{f.IntialProceeds}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[31]" class="tableItem" >
                            <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.IntialProceeds" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" />
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[32]" class="tableItem">{{f.PaymentInDays}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[32]" class="tableItem" >
                            <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.PaymentInDays" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" />
                        </td>


                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[33]" class="tableItem">
                            {{f.PaymentTypeOfDaysName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[33]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;" [(ngModel)]="f.PaymentTypeOfDaysId"
                                [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm"
                                [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqTypeOfDays" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                                [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>

                        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[34]"></td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[35]" class="tableItem">{{f.HoldbackPercentage}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[35]" class="tableItem">
                            <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.HoldbackPercentage"
                                style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" />
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[36]" class="tableItem">{{f.HoldbackPayment}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[36]" class="tableItem" >
                            <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.HoldbackPayment" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" />
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[37]" class="tableItem">
                            {{f.HoldbackTypeOfDaysName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[37]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;"
                                [(ngModel)]="f.HoldbackTypeOfDaysId" [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
                                class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqTypeOfDays"
                                [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>

                        <td colspan=i class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[38] && i<1"></td>

                        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[39]">
                            <div *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id]">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" style="float: left;"
                                    (click)="reviewClicked(f.value.Id,2)">Review Fees</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[40]" class="tableItem">{{f.ManagementFeeRate}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[40]" class="tableItem" >
                            <kendo-numerictextbox [(ngModel)]="f.ManagementFeeRate"
                                style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;"></kendo-numerictextbox>
                            <!-- <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.ManagementFeeRate" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" /> -->
                        </td>


                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[41]" class="tableItem">{{f.IncentiveFeeRate}}
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[41]" class="tableItem" >
                            <kendo-numerictextbox [(ngModel)]="f.IncentiveFeeRate" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;">
                            </kendo-numerictextbox>
                            <!-- <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.IncentiveFeeRate" style="width: 100%; height: 29.5px;" /> -->
                        </td>


                        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[42]" class="tableItem">
                            {{f.RealizationFrequencyName}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[42]" class="tableItem">
                            <kendo-dropdownlist style="height: 29.5px;"
                                [(ngModel)]="f.RealizationFrequencyId" [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
                                class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="LegalFundClasses.LiqFrequencys"
                                [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                            </kendo-dropdownlist>
                        </td>







                        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[57]">

                            <button *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 "
                                (click)="buttonClicked(f.Id)">Edit</button>
                            <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 "
                                (click)="Update(f.Id)">Save</button>
                            <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 "
                                (click)="Delete(f.Id)">Delete</button>
                            <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 "
                                (click)="buttonClicked(f.Id)">Cancel</button>

                        </td>
                    </ng-container> 
                    </ng-container>
                    <!-- </ng-container> -->
                </ng-container>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not building your array normally.

Usually, an HTML array goes line by line : you go column by column.

You have to change your way of building the array.

[Here is the working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ok0u78r/) (I have sliced the data to avoid too much data on the screen)

```html
    <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index; first as first; last as last">
    <td>{{ col }}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let item of data.slice(0, 3)">
      {{ first ? item.Description : last ? item.Id : item.AuditSummary }}
    </td>   
    <td *ngFor="let item1 of data1.slice(0, 3)">
      {{ first ? item1.Description : last ? item1.Id : item1.AuditSummary }}
    </td>   
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: In my actual code  I am having 50 tds. So you mean I would have 50 + 50 tds and there will be loop for each td

Comment: @Tom well yes, I mean that's on you, you don't build your table properly (i.e. The way html intended you to). If I may suggest, you should drop the concept of array and use either another html concept (such as flex boxes) or a library capable of managing such arrays.

Comment: I have spent an awful time with this table and need to try and fix

Comment: Another question that I have is most of tds have ngIf will it allow me to use ngIf and ngFor for the same td

Comment: In your jsfiddle you are missing the key field LegalParentClassId . Could you check my fiddle again https://jsfiddle.net/205zkm8o/